# How to make JTable column contain checkboxes?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, tablecellrenderer

Preface: I am horrible with java, and worse with java ui components.

I have found several different tutorials on how to add buttons to tables, however I am struggling with adding checkboxes. I need to have a column that draws a text box ticked on default (cell renderer i think handles that), then on click of tickbox, unticks the box, redraws said box, and fires off an event somewhere I can track.

currently I have a custom cellrenderer:

```
public class GraphButtonCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {
public GraphButtonCellRenderer() {
}
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if(isSelected)
        setSelected(true);
    else
        setSelected(false);
    setMargin(new Insets(0, 16, 0, 0));
    setIconTextGap(0);

    setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,0));
    return this;
}}
```

Which currently handles drawing the tick box, but only ticks and unticks the box if that row is selected. But I don't know how to handle the events. Really what I am asking is possibly a link to a good tutorial on how to add checkboxes cleanly to a JTable.
Any assist is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's no need to create your own table renderer.  [Here's a simpler example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingdefaultBooleanvaluecelleditorandrenderer.htm).  Just create a custom table model and for a given column return the class Boolean for:

```
public Class getColumnClass(int column)
```

If you want the column to be editable, return true for

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
```

JTable takes care of the rendering for you.

[Another example is here.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: +1 Good point; simpler may suffice. The tutorial describes several default renderers for specific classes.

Comment: Accepted. Thank you very much for the links, these are simple enough for me to follow/integrate with my current project

Answer (score 6):

As Peter say, its easy using extended DefaultTableModel class, ex:

```
class NewTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a <strike>simple</strike> rather elaborate [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) using a `TableCellRenderer` and `TableCellEditor`. See also, [*Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Addendum: @Jay Askren's point is well taken. The default renderer for `Boolean.class`, as described in the tutorial, may be all you need.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't come across that particular example. So much stuff going on... I'll give it a crack

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to use the DefaultTableModel and use Boolean object as values.

Comment: yeah that's true @Peter,
But could we enhance more by adding some value (ID) to that checkbox if we want the TRUE value become an ID value, and FALSE still FALSE value?

Answer (score -5):

In the Swing Designer set column type to boolean

Comment: this solution assumes the OP is using a UI builder of some type