# Jtable checkboxes are not editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I know its a very basic question I have checkboxes in my tables's first column Problem is checkboxes are not clickable.I have searched for similar threads and tried to  assign the Boolean editor to the column  and to override the getColumnClass()But I couldnt do it  This is what I have tried so far

```
String[] columnNames = {"Column 1", "Column 2"};  
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);  
table=new JTable(model );  
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer( table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class) );  

ArrayList<org.jsoup.nodes.Element >arr=GetrowCount("http://www.mit.edu/");
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element element :  arr) {
    Object[]  rows = {Boolean.FALSE, element};  
    model.addRow( rows );
}

scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);

panel.add(scrollPane);
this.add(panel);
this.setSize(300,300);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JCheckBox` is not editable because you set `Renderer` for column, but for editing you need add `Editor`, read more about [Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Another way is to override `getColumnClass()` method of `TableModel` and return `Boolean.class` for column:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String... s) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        String[] columnNames = {"Column 1", "Column 2"};  
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0){
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnIndex == 0 ? Boolean.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }
        };  
        JTable table=new JTable(model );  

        for (int i =0;i<5;i++) {
            Object[]  rows = {Boolean.FALSE, i};  
            model.addRow( rows );
        }

        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom table model that will return the checkbox column as editable. Check this link for more info and examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901500/1843508

Comment: Yes I know that link I have checked it out before .But when I use  custom model I am having trouble while adding rows.Is it possible  to stick to code